# UISwitch Custom Size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiswitch

I have created a `UISwitch` in the Interface Builder. Its default size is 51x31

I have put constraints on it to make it smaller size 33x20

It shows smaller in the Interface Builder but on runtime it does not obey to the size constraints.

Elsewhere is it told that `UISwitch` is a special control and does not like to obey size constraints. Is it true?

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Change Edge inset of UISwitch

Comment: i also want to make switch smaller in size . did you get the way ? how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

As simple instead of creating a `UISwitch` , create `UIButton` and set background image as you want. Here set 2 background images for `UIButton` for 2 states. Just toggle the `UIButton` between these 2 states

Comment: Thanks but not what I am looking for. I want actual UISwitch in smaller size.